# Collection of Generic Objects. Auto-Casting? Hidden Casting?

Tags: java, generics

I'm attempting to hold node properties in the following manner (this may be inherently wrong):

```
public class Property<T> {
    protected String key;
    protected T value;

    public Property(String key, T value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }
}


public class Node {
    protected HashMap<String,Property> properties;

    public Node() {
        properties = new HashMap<>();
    }
```

However, this has the unfortunate side effect of making my a giant mess of casting. I've been reading everything that might be relevant, but nothing seems to address the essentail problem. Here's my current thought:

```
    public void add(String key, Object value) {
        if ( ! (value instanceof Property)) {
            value = new Property<>(key, value);
        }
        properties.put(key, (Property)value);
    }

    public long get(String key, long x) {
        return (long)properties.get(key).value;
    }
    public long[] get(String key, long[] x) {
        return (long[])properties.get(key).value;
    }
    public String get(String key, String x) {
        return (String)properties.get(key).value;
    }
    // etc
```

Now this is obviously incrediably stupid, but I'm going around in circles trying to simply be able to grab a node property by key, and be assured of it's type based on the key.

It's that simple. **A given key must correspond to a given type, both for adding and for getting**.

I honestly feel like I'm misunderstanding something fundamental about the nature of Java.

Comment: Do you have to use string keys, or would a custom type be acceptable?

Comment: A custom type might be okay. The string keys are arbitrary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the node class can hold properties of any value type, you need to make an **unchecked cast** anyways. There's no need to overload the `get` function, you can **cast to whatever the expected return type is**:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public <T> T get(String key) {
    return (T) properties.get(key).value;
}
```

Examples:

```
Node node = new Node();
node.add("x", 123);
node.add("y", "ABC");
node.add("z", new Date());

int    valueX = node.get("x"); // cast to integer and autobox to int
String valueY = node.get("y"); // cast to String
Date   valueZ = node.get("z"); // cast to Date

String valueFail = node.get("z"); // this will throw a ClassCastException
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
// a node representing things of type T
public class Node<T> {
    protected HashMap<String,Property<T>> properties;

    public Node() {
        properties = new HashMap<>();
    }

    // add a T to the map
    public void add(String key, T value) {
        properties.put(key, new Property<T>(string, value));
    }
}
```

What concerns me about your example, so far, is that a "Node" looks quite a lot like a hashmap Entry. A better question would be "what are you REALLY trying to do"?

Comment: Ah, I seem to need to clarify my question. See part one of Sotirios' answer. Your suggestion is nifty, but not what I'm trying to do

Comment: Hi Michael - you're not telling us what you're trying to do, you're telling us how you're trying to implement it. What's the purpose of this data structure? What real world problem are you trying to solve? There are other patterns which may help...

Comment: nodes represent shapes in an image (acquired with computer vision). Properties are shape name, size, angles, fill, etc.

Answer (score 2):

> A given key must correspond to a given type, both for adding and for getting.

Assuming you mean for the `String key` to be an identifier for the element **and its type**, then you're out of luck, it's simply impossible with generics. One option is to define a custom class with appropriately typed field/getters for each known property.

If you mean for the `x` parameter, then you can use generics to do something like

```
public <T> T get(String key, T x) {
    return (T) properties.get(key).value;
}
```

but this sets you up for all sorts of `ClassCastException`. Your compiler should warn against this. (Note, also, that you won't be able to use primitive types directly.)

Comment: Interesting. I mean the former. That's unfortunate, but thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to write an externally typesafe implementation of this, though it'll require some internal casting that the compiler can't prove is correct.

```
class TypeSafeMap {
  public static final class Key<T> {
    // deliberately empty; we're knowingly using reference equality
  }

  private final Map<Key<?>, Object> map;

  TypeSafeMap() {
    this.map = new HashMap<>();
  }

  public <T> T get(Key<T> key) {
    return (T) map.get(key); // cast is safe, but the compiler can't prove it
  }

  public <T> void put(Key<T> key, T value) {
    map.put(key, value);
  }
}

class SomewhereElse {
  static final Key<Integer> myIntKey = new Key<Integer>();
  static final Key<String> myStringKey = new Key<String>();

  public void doWhatever(TypeSafeMap myMap) {
    int myInt = myMap.get(myIntKey);
    String myString = myMap.get(myStringKey);
  }
}
```

...That said, if you know the entire set of keys in advance, you can (and should) make a custom class with appropriately typed fields, rather than trying to squeeze the whole thing into a map-like structure.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Node
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
        Node node = new Node();
        node.addProperty("a", 12L);
        node.addProperty("b", "i'm a string");

        long number = node.getProperty("a");
        String string = node.getProperty("b");
    }

    private Map<String, Object> properties = new HashMap<>();

    public void addProperty(String key, Object value){
        this.properties.put(key, value);
    }

    public <T> T getProperty(String key){
        return (T) this.properties.get(key);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The OP is trying to handle a collection of different objects, so generics aren't the way forward. What he's trying to do is have type-safe processing of each specific object within a collection. Here's how you could do that using the visitor pattern.

```
// Implement this interface in something which needs to process
// an item from the collection in a way specific to the type of that item
interface Visitor {
    void visit(Circle c);
    void visit(Square s);
}

class Collection {
    Map<String, Shape> shapes = new HashMap<>();

    void add(String key, Shape shape) {
        shapes.put(key, shape);
    }


    // when you want to process what's behind a key, send in a visitor
    void visit(String key, Visitor visitor) {
        // ask the shape to be visited by the visitor
        shapes.get(key).visit(visitor);
    }
 }


 interface Shape { 
     void visit(Visitor visitor);
 }


 class Circle implements Shape {
     void visit(Visitor visitor) {
         // tells the visitor to treat this object as a circle
         visitor.visit(this);
     }
 }
```

Let's say you wanted something which draws a particular shape from the collection.

```
 class DrawingVisitor implements Visitor {
     void visit(Circle c) {
         // use properties only a circle has to draw it
         graphics2d.ellipse(c.getRadius(), c.getCenterPoint()); 
     }

     void visit(Square s) {
         graphics2d.rectangle(s.getTopLeft(), s.getBottomRight());
     }
 }
```

Etc

Make sense?